# text box should display values from database when value selected from drop-down in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to display tax details of a particular company from database when company name is selected from drop-down box in the same form without altering other values. 
I am using jsp and servlet.
please help...

Comment: "*without altering other values*"? Do not understand. If you meant, "*without refreshing the whole page*" then, you would need to use some Ajaxical tricks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time.I have never used Ajax,is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Thank you Tiny. I got solution.

Comment: You should not utterly thank me just for leaving a simple comment. :)